# Open Telemetry for react and vanilla JS projects

Tags: open-telemetry

Can someone help me understand if there is a way to configure open Telemetry on the client side for react and vanilla JS projects all I want to do is to console the traces of fetch call that are being made from the browser.

Most of the documentation I see is only for nodejs. Pls pinpoint a documentation if there are any?

Answer (score 1):

The documentation gives a common guide for Javascript. What you do for you React would be same as what you do for Node.js or even simple JS scripts.

Just follow the [documentation](https://opentelemetry.io/docs/instrumentation/js/getting-started/browser/). Create and export a tracer:

```
import { ZoneContextManager } from '@opentelemetry/context-zone';
import { registerInstrumentations } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation';
import { DocumentLoadInstrumentation } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-document-load';
import { FetchInstrumentation } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-fetch';
import { UserInteractionInstrumentation } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-user-interaction';
import { XMLHttpRequestInstrumentation } from '@opentelemetry/instrumentation-xml-http-request';
import { ConsoleSpanExporter, SimpleSpanProcessor } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-base';
import { WebTracerProvider } from '@opentelemetry/sdk-trace-web';

const setupTracer = () => {
    const provider = new WebTracerProvider();

    provider.addSpanProcessor(new SimpleSpanProcessor(new ConsoleSpanExporter()));
    
    provider.register({
      // Changing default contextManager to use ZoneContextManager - supports asynchronous operations - optional
      contextManager: new ZoneContextManager(),
    });
    
    // Registering instrumentations
    registerInstrumentations({
      instrumentations: [
        new DocumentLoadInstrumentation(),
        new UserInteractionInstrumentation(),
        new XMLHttpRequestInstrumentation(),
        new FetchInstrumentation()
      ],
    });
    
}

export default setupTracer;
```

Import the tracer like this in your app's entry point (usually `index.js`):

```
setupTracer();
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```